# Pandas count occurrences

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

Hi I have datamodel like this:

```
Number    Type
123       A
123       B
455       B
455       A
455       C
```

and I need to make some kind of a pivot table like this:

```
Number    A    B    C    SUM
123       1    1    0    2
455       1    1    1    3
```

Tried with pandas pivot table but with no positive results

Thank you

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df['Number'], df['Type'], margins=True)`.

Comment: Didnt work, gives me KeyError: "Type"

Comment: Then you need to see your data for the correct column name, is it `Type` or `Type ` or `Type         `.

Comment: Number collumn is int64 (dtype), Type collumn is object (dtype)

Comment: `print(df.columns)` see if it's `'Type'` or `'Type '`?

Comment: Index(['Number', 'Type'],  dtype='object')

Comment: Then there's no reason for `KeyError: "Type"`, you can try: `pd.crosstab(df.iloc[:, 0], df.iloc[:, 1])`...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now it works. Maybe a some kind of typo on first try...

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `crosstab` then assign the count of unique `Number` to a new `SUM` column

```py
out = (pd.crosstab(df['Number'], df['Type'])
       .assign(SUM=df['Number'].value_counts())
       .reset_index())
```

```
print(out)

Type  Number  A  B  C  SUM
0        123  1  1  0    2
1        455  1  1  1    3
```

Comment: Didnt work, gives me KeyError: "Type"